# Can't bind to angular datepicker

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using https://github.com/alongubkin/angular-datepicker in an ionic app becuase I dont want to add jQuery as I would only be using it for the calendar.

I have defaulted the date to today's date in my controller and I am trying to bind to the date selected in the calendar but it doesn't update the selectedDate...

```
 <input type="button" class="button" pick-a-date="selectedDate" data-ng-model="selectedDate"/>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['angular-datepicker']);

function MyCtrl($scope, $rootScope) {
$rootScope.selectedDate = new Date();
}
```

If I dont default to today - the scope is still not updated when someone chooses a date

Answer (score 0):

You need do:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $rootScope) {
      $scope.selectedDate = new Date();
}
```

Your model isn´t generated in $rootScope. In ng-model documentation you can see

> Note: ngModel will try to bind to the property given by evaluating the expression on the current scope. If the property doesn't already exist on this scope, it will be created implicitly and added to the scope.

I suposse that your *MyCtrl* is attached in view (< html ng-controller="MyCtrl" >).

Also, [you can use $rootScope](http://www.bestscode.com/0JNSmUPUQWeQ/angularjs-ngmodel-input-type-number-to-rootscope-not-updating) but I do not recommend it.

Good luck!

Comment: I have added the controller to the document - all the other angular functions and variables are working fine. I tried adding it to $scope instead and it still doesn't work - $scope.selectedDate just stays as today not matter what date you choose in the calendar

Comment: Sorry, if you need bind calendar and  scope you must use the directiva ng-model. For example in your dataPicker put ng-model=myDate and in your scope you will can access to value like "scope.myDate".